# get a model from other controller in emberjs in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, ember.js

I got a problem with a bigger project in ember,
I want to get information from a model when i'm in a template that is not associated with the controller for that model.

I got these templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="community">
   {{model.name}}
   {{outlet}}
</script>

//users is a subroute from community
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="communityUsers">
   //assume i want to display something from a community here like:
   {{community.id}}
   {{#each user in model}}
     <li>{{user.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

in the routes I fetch the appropriate models so for the community i got 1 community and in the communityUsers i have an array with users

does anyone know the best solution for this?

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem in a more specific way. What information do you want from model? Don't ask for "the best solution" but ask specifically for a solution that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a problem with a bigger project in ember, I want to get information from a model when i'm in a template that is not associated with the controller for that model.

Assuming you get your communities like this:

```
App.CommunityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Community.find();
  }
});
```

Further assuming you want to have access from a controller that is not related to your `CommunityController` (which get's it's content set after the model hook returns) you could use the `needs` API and define a dependance to it

```
App.CommunityUsersController = Ember.Objectontroller.extend({
  // here dependence definition
  needs: ['community'],
  // create an observer that returns the community you want
  // I've chosen just the first one
  choosenCommunity: function() {
    return this.get('controllers.community').objectAt(0);
  }.observes('controllers.community')
});
```

So now in your `communityUsers` template you are able to access those properties

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="communityUsers">
   //assume i want to display something from a community here like:
   {{choosenCommunity.id}}
   {{#each user in choosenCommunity.users}}
     <li>{{user.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

And the best of all this, everything will stay up to date since it's bound.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So from what I've understood, you are trying to access the model of `communityController` inside the template of it's child template `communityUsers`.
For that you've to define your `communityUsersController` to need the `communityController` by

```
needs: ['community']
```

and then in your template

```
{{#each user in controllers.community.model}}
 <li>{{user.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```